# Rendering the Kinect output with GLUT in Visual Studio 2013 C++ (Stack overflow)

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013, kinect, glut

I have been trying to port some useful code for a project, but I'm experiencing some difficulty in making GLUT work properly. Whenever the cbRender function is called, Visual Studio pops up an exception saying that there was a Stack Overflow: "Unhandled exception at 0x00FAD357 in KinectBridgeWithOpenCVBasics-D2D.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00272000)."

I have tried putting a breakpoint right at the declaration of cbRender, and by going into the next step has got me in a "chkstk.asm not found" VB page.

Here's my main function so far:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

HRESULT hr = NuiInitialize(
    NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_DEPTH_AND_PLAYER_INDEX
    | NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_COLOR);

if (hr != S_OK)
{
    cout << "NuiInitialize failed" << endl;
    return hr;
}

// Initialize Display Mode
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH);

// Initialize OpenGL Window
glutInitWindowSize(window_width, window_height);
glutInitWindowPosition(window_xpos, window_ypos);
GLwindow = glutCreateWindow("Kinect Registration");
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

// Initialize OpenCV Window
namedWindow("Camera 0 | Camera 1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

// Setup The GL Callbacks
glutDisplayFunc(cbRender);
glutReshapeFunc(cbReSizeGLScene);
glutKeyboardFunc(cbKeyPressed);
glutMotionFunc(cbMouseMoved);
glutMouseFunc(cbMousePress);
glutTimerFunc(10, cbTimer, 10);

// Setup The CV Callbacks
cvSetMouseCallback("Camera 0 | Camera 1", cbMouseEvent);

glutMainLoop();

NuiShutdown();

return 0;
}
```

And the cbRender function:

```
void cbRender() {

    short xyz[window_height][window_width][3];
    unsigned char rgb[window_height][window_width][3];
    unsigned int indices[window_height][window_width];

    //Flush the OpenCV Mat's from last frame
    rgbCV.clear();
    depthCV.clear();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(zoom, zoom, 1);
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 3.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0, 0);
    glRotatef(rotangles[0], 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(rotangles[1], 0, 1, 0);
    draw_axes();

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glPointSize(2);
    //--------Camera 0 (P)-----------
    loadBuffers(0, indices, xyz, rgb);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_SHORT, 0, xyz);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, rgb);
    glPushMatrix();
    // transform centroid of P to origin and rotate
    transformation(0);
    // projection matrix (camera specific - Can be improved)
    loadVertexMatrix();
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, window_width*window_height);
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

I realize that most of the actual code is hidden away in functions, and if any of those functions can be causing the problem just say so and I will provide the code for them, too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see immediately a problem with your code, however I can give some advice: There are two possible reasons for a stack overflow:

- the amount of available stack is exceeded by allocating an object in automatic storage.
- a (set of) function is calling themself recursively without properly terminating the recursion.

Luckily stack overflows are very easy to debug: Run your program in a debugger, let the stack overflow happen and retrieve a backtrace / stack trace using the debugger. This will exactly show you which function call(s) are causing the problem.